# Spring jackson can't parse JSON Object

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, jackson

I Have entity Users

```
    public class Users implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
        private String password;
        private String email;
        private Boolean enabled;
        private String name;
        private String lastname;
        private String userRole;
        private String secondName;
        private String telephone;
        private String automobile;
        private List<Claim> claims;
        private List<Orders> ordersList;
    // getters and setters
}
```

User has many claims and orders. And my controller method such like this

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "get", method = GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Users get() {
        return ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserInfo();
    }
```

And then i try to get user, i get this error
    at

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:694)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:672)
//etc
```

All my entities implements Serializible interface.
But if i try something like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "get", method = GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Users get() {

        Users users = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUserInfo();
        users.setClaims(null);
        users.setOrdersList(null);
        return users;

    }
```

and it works.
I get json string like this

```
{
  "id" : 7,
  "password" : "$2a$11$IDMDPHQNiNEs9NP282zrGe3rn8la5WL8aR.RY3IFFa8y0NJc9ubdS",
  "email" : "serendipity@mail.ru",
  "enabled" : true,
  "name" : "Alex",
  "lastname" : "Zhukov",
  "userRole" : "ROLE_USER",
  "secondName" : null,
  "telephone" : "89274455166",
  "automobile" : "MercedesW222",
  "claims" : null,
  "ordersList" : null
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
My pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Upd**
Claims and orders entities

```
   public class Orders implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
        private String status;
        private String address;
        private Timestamp fDate;
        private Integer sum;
        private Users users;
        private List<OrdersProducts> ordersProductsList;
//getters and setters
}
public class Claim implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Timestamp fDate;
    private String reason;
    private String status;
    private String response;
    private Users user;
    private Integer sum;
    //getters and setters
    }
```

Apparently , he goes into a deep recursion. User has many claims and orders, and orders & claims belongs to user. 
And so on to infinity. 
But then again , in this case , i must set to null  claims and orders?

Comment: Could you also share your Claim and Orders entities

Comment: I think problem is inside the Claim and Orders objects

Comment: You've posted part of the stacktrace, can you post the full thing, especially the error message itself?

Comment: Serializable means using byte code; it has nothing to do with JSON.  Jackson is very robust. Try reading and writing each object before combining them. Might be that the Timestamp is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular reference on your entities. Please take a look at @JsonIdentityInfo annotation. And maybe below solution can help

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Claim implements Serializable {}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Orders implements Serializable {}
```